# @Scheduled annotation is not working properly?

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks

i am using spring annotaions with `<task:annotation-driven/>`

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay=100)
    public void shout(){
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
```

this is printing only 9 times, but i want it to print infinitely.

Comment: Did the programm end after 1 second?

Comment: yes it is ending after some time not exactly one second

Comment: sorry, its working fine when i run after server running, but its not running through JUnit testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you and the behavior, then the problem seams to be that the containing Application, Test, whatever just ends.

A Spring Scheduler does not hold the application open. If the spring context ends, because the application ends, then the timer also stops.